# Introductory reference on rationality and irrationality of real numbers

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, irrational-numbers

I am looking for a good reference on the proof of the rationality or the irrationality of some real numbers.

I think these kinds of problems show a nice variety of proofs and techniques, ranging from arithmetic (Euclid's proof of the irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$, criteria to determine whether $\frac{\ln(a)}{\ln(b)}$ is rational or not (for $a,b$ integers),...) to calculus (irrationality of $\pi$ or $e$,...), passing through algebra (Rational Root Test to prove the irrationality of $n^{th}$ roots of integers,...).

I am not looking for a survey of the state of the art, but an introduction to these problems.

Comment: Honestly, I think this is too broad. The techniques used to prove these facts often are completely disjoint from each other, and I don't think any meaningful answers can be given generally. As such, I've voted to close.

Comment: @RushabhMehta: Maybe. There are books dedicated to the properties of $\pi$, with extremely different points of view. Thanks for explaining your VTC.

Comment: @RushabhMehta: It should be possible to give an answer that meets some of the expectations, if all the expectations are too much. Such a partial answer will be meaningful and useful. So voting to close addresses nothing.

Comment: https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/niven.pdf

Answer (score 3):

I highly recommend Ivan Niven's monographs

1. *Numbers: Rational and Irrational*, and
2. *Irrational Numbers*.

They are both excellent introductions to the topics that you have mentioned you want to study.

Comment: It seems to satisfy my needs. I am waiting for other answers during a few days before accepting it.